# mysql query to identify and delete duplicates based on timestamp

Tags: mysql

I am trying to build a mysql query to list all column a's that have a duplicate column b from a single table. The trick is I have a timestamp on the rows so i need to essentially identify which is the older of the duplicates so i can delete it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: post some sample data ... n wat u hav tried..

Comment: SELECT *,
 COUNT(foocode) AS NumOccurrences
FROM table
GROUP BY foocode
HAVING ( COUNT(foocode) > 1 ) ORDER BY foolastmodified ASC

Comment: i am not strong with mysql at this point... clearly that didnt work i cant even see the duplicate records with this as it just shows me the column and the amount of times it occurred and orders the whole thing by the time stamps if i am correct? I would like it to show the duplicate records, group them by the column, ordered by the timestamp, and then eventually have the capability to just delete the older duplicate

Comment: Post some sample data what u have from ur table.. Its tough to assume ur data n write the SQL query...

Comment: The answers so far are looking @ rows with the same column value, however the OP states cola = colb. Which is it?

Comment: I apologize I meant to phrase my question as if the column has a duplicate, group all duplicates together, show the timestamps for each duplicate record, list the timestamps in order for the duplicates within the duplicate group and then delete the duplicates with the older timestamps. Looking back at how I originally asked the question it didnt make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just example - this query return duplicate posts, now you just need to execute delete

```
id| title     | text_desc          | created 
-------------------------------------------------------
1 | The title | description here   |2012-02-21 10:58:58
2 | The title | description here 1 |2012-02-21 10:58:58
3 | The title | description here 3 |2012-02-21 10:58:58

    select bad_rows.*
     from posts as bad_rows
      inner join (
       select title, MIN(id) as min_id
          from posts
           group by title
             having count(*) > 1
          ) as good_rows on good_rows.title = bad_rows.title
            and good_rows.min_id <> bad_rows.id;
```

Here is the return rows

```
id| title     | text_desc          | created 
-------------------------------------------------------
2 | The title | description here 1 |2012-02-21 10:58:58
3 | The title | description here 3 |2012-02-21 10:58:58
```

Comment: thank you for adding the visual example it makes it easy to follow

Answer (score 3):

Here's your query:

```
DELETE FROM tablename
WHERE id IN
(SELECT t1.id
 FROM tablename t1
 JOIN tablename t2
   ON t2.cola = t1.cola AND t2.colb = t1.colb
   AND t2.timecol > t1.timecol
 WHERE t1.cola = t1.colb)
```

The SELECT statement returns records where `cola = colb` and there are other matching rows with a later date. The DELETE statement deletes all records returned by the SELECT.

If you're looking to remove duplicate `cola`, then this is the query:

```
DELETE FROM tablename
WHERE id IN
(SELECT t1.id
 FROM tablename t1
 JOIN tablename t2
   ON t2.cola = t1.cola
   AND t2.timecol > t1.timecol)
```

Comment: If the OP does in fact want colA = colB this looks like the answer he/she is looking for.

Comment: Thank you for both queries I need to spend more time researching  subqueries

Comment: my table name is general2 so when i ran the command i get this error: "You can't specify target table 'general2' for update in FROM clause" any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FOOCODE,COUNT(*) AS DUPS
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY FOOCODE
HAVING COUNT(FOOCODE)>1;
```

The above query will return u all the duplicates.Is this what u are looking for?

Comment: Well this would give me the column and a count of the number occurences correct? Lets say something has an occurence of 3 times... I need to identify the older occurences so i can delete them and just keep the newest one.

Comment: So u hav a timestamp column existing for each dup... ? Can u copy ur data n post it ...

Comment: I do have a timestamp. Data would look something along the lines of column a ==fooprodcode, column b ==foodescription, column c == foosku, column d == footimestamp. Does this help? So lets say we have a duplicate sku. I need to identify  the duplicate sku, order the timestamps within this duplicate sku group, and identify which is the newest timestamp so i can delete all of the records within that duplicate group that are older? Idk if I explained that very well.. let me know